# Validate that a given string (name) meets certain requirements

Tags: c#, .net

```
String Name = "yyyy MM DD abjwg kelk.exe"

public static bool IsNameRight(string Name)
{
    string[] temp = Name.Split(' ');
    string[] de= Name.Split('.');

    if (de[1] == "pdf" && temp .Length == 5)
    {
        if (temp [0].Length == 4
            && temp [1].Length == 2 
            && temp [3].Length == 2
            && temp [4] == "abjwg" 
            && temp [5] == "kelk.exe")
            return true;
        else
            return false;
    }
    return false;
}
```

I am using .NET 3.5 and C#

**EDIT**

You could use Regular expressions but I have never used it or know how to use it, and don't know if it is a good practice.

Comment: What will this code do if given `foo.pdf.exe`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The method name would be better called `IsNameValid` and the parameter `name` should be camel cased.

```
public static bool IsNameValid(string name)
{
    // firstly always validate parameters, either throw an exception or return false.
    if (name == null) { throw new ArgumentNullException("name"); }

    // use more descriptive variable names, what does 'de' mean?
    string[] temp = name.Split(' ');
    string[] de= name.Split('.');

    // check that the arrays contain the correct number of values or you will get an exception accessing the indexer.
    if (de.Lengh < 2 || temp.Length < 5) { return false; }

    return de[1] == "pdf"
            && temp[0].Length == 4
            && temp[1].Length == 2 
            && temp[2].Length == 2
            && temp[3] == "abjwg" 
            && temp[4] == "kelk.exe";
}
```

Comment: It also would be better if you wrap the statements after return into another method: 

return hasValidArgumentAndExtensions(de, temp);

Answer (score 15):

As you wanted to use RegEx I have a recommendation for you:

```
public static bool IsValidName(string Name)
{
    if(String.IsNullOrEmpty(Name))
        return new ArgumentNullException();

    string pattern = @"^[0-9]{4} [0-9]{2} [0-9]{2} abjwg kelk\\.exe$";
    return Regex.IsMatch(Name, pattern);
}
```

Comment: getting error here "\.exe$" for the decimal

Comment: you may want to try to escape the backslash by using another backslash: `kelk\\.exe$`

Answer (score 10):

If you are trying to get the extension of a file, I would use

System.Io.Path.GetExtension

**Update**

Since de seem to only be used for getting the extension.

```
string[] de= Name.Split('.');
```

could be changed to

```
string de = System.Io.Path.GetExtension(Name);
```

Comment: You might want to add a code example of what you are suggesting.

Answer (score 8):

```
private static readonly Regex pattern = new Regex(@"[0-9]{4} [0-9]{2} [0-9]{2} [A-Za-z0-9]{5} [A-Za-z0-9]{4}\.exe");

public static bool IsNameRight(string name)
{
    return pattern.IsMatch(name);
}
```

- `[0-9]` means a character which is a digit between 0 and 9.
- `[A-Za-z0-9]` means a character which is between A and Z (uppercase) or a and z (lowercase) or a digit between 0-9.
- `{4}` exactly four times

Comment: if the whole executable name is variable yours is of course better than mine

Comment: @fix_likes_coding: I believe it is based upon 'As I want to confirm that my string is in this format "yyyy MM dd ABCDE FGHI.EXE"'.

Answer (score 2):

I can think of at least few things with the code. Skip some of the redundant `else` and `if` clasues.

```
String name = "yyyy MM DD abjwg kelk.exe"

public static bool IsNameRight(string Name)
{
    string[] temp = Name.Split(' ');
    string[] de = Name.Split('.');

    if (de[1] != "pdf" && temp.Length != 5)
      return false;

  if (temp [0].Length == 4
    && temp [1].Length == 2 
    && temp [3].Length == 2
    && temp [4] == "abjwg" 
    && temp [5] == "kelk.exe")
    return true;
  return false;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's another way of improving your code:

```
String name = "yyyy MM DD abjwg kelk.exe"

public static bool isNameRight( string name )
{
    string[] de   = name.Split( "." );
    string[] temp = de[0].Split( " " );

    if ( ! ( de[1] == "pdf" && temp.Length == 5 ) )
        return false;

    return ( temp[0].Length == 4
                && temp[1].Length == 2 
                && temp[2].Length == 2
                && temp[3] == "abjwg" 
                && temp[4] == "kelk" );
}
```

I know this isn't about finding and fixing bugs, but it seemed important to note that given your **name** string and your function logic, it will always return false, because you're testing for `temp [5] == "kelk.exe"` after `de[1] == "pdf"` so in this case, if **de[1]** equals "pdf" then **temp[5]** will never have the **.exe** part, it would have **.pdf**. That's also why I removed the extension from **temp[4]** value.

Additionally, I would use @the_lotus way of dealing with the file extension.

I hope you find this helpful.